# On continuity and existence of all directional derivatives at a point of a scalar field whose gradient at that point is $\vec 0$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be a function such that for some $a \in \mathbb R^2$ , $\nabla f(a)$ exists and equals $\vec 0$.

1. Is $f$ necessarily continuous at $a$ ?
2. Do all directional derivatives $f'(a;y)$ exist at $a$?
3. Suppose $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $\nabla f(a)=0$. Do the directional derivatives at $a$ exist in this case?

Comment: If partial derivatives exist and are continuous, then directional derivatives in all directions exist.

Comment: @GEdgar : Actually it requires to exist in a naighbourhood , not only at one point ..

Comment: How do you define $\nabla f(a)$? Is it the unique vector $v$ that satisfies $f(a+x)=f(a)+x\cdot v+o(|x|)$ or a vector whose components are partial derivatives?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta  No. You are writing the definition of differentiability. It does not follow from mere existence of partial derivatives. $\nabla f(a)$ is just the vector of partial derivatives.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta : It is just the vector whose components are the partial derivatives at $a$

Comment: Yes, in order for something to be continuous (such as a partial derivative) it must exist in a neighborhood.

Comment: @GEdgar -- What is the question to which your answer is "Yes"?

Comment: @uniquesolution, I would find it natural to say that $\nabla f(a)$ is the differential of $f$ at $a$, its existence thus implying differentiability. (This kind of gradient is invariant under linear changes of coordinates, the vector of partial derivatives is not.) I wanted to ask to be sure. In a low regularity setting I find it important to make sure that we have the same definitions, that's all.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta  - Well, you are wrong. It is not natural to say it is the differential, for the simple reason that $f$ may have a gradient but fail to be differentiable!

Comment: @SaunDev After reading the title, the question body (three times), and perusing the existing answers and comments, I'm lost as to what is actually being asked. Could you please edit your question to explain (i) What is your definition of $\nabla f(a)$; (ii) What conditions you are imposing on $f$; and (iii) In light of (ii), what property to wish $f$ to have, or wish to seen proven $f$ _cannot_ have? (And then please edit the title to match the question.) Thanks. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang : I hope it is clear now :)

Comment: Yes, that's helpful. :) One last clarification: $\nabla f(a)$ is the vector of partial derivatives of $f$ at $a$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to all your questions is "no".

For 1, there are [discontinuous functions whose partial derivatives exist and are equal to zero in all directions](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~js/Math202/example2.pdf).

As for 2 and 3., the answer is "no" again. Consider $f(x,y)=x^{1/3}y^{1/3}$. $f(x,y)$ is continuous at the origin, and the gradient is zero at $(0,0)$ because $f$ is zero along the axes, but it doesn't have directional derivatives in other directions: Indeed:
$$\frac{f(hy_1,hy_1)-f(0,0)}{h}=\frac{h^{2/3}y_1^{1/3}y_2^{1/3}}{h}\approx h^{-1/3}$$
and so the limit does isn't finite as $h\to 0$.

Comment: What about the second question ? Does $f'(a,y)$ exists for all $y \in \mathbb R^2$ ? Your note does not provide a counterexample to this second one

Comment: What does $f^{'}(a,y)$ mean? If it means the directional derivative at $a$ in the direction $y$, then yes, the attached note takes care of that too.

Comment: $f'(a;y):= \lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f(a+hy)-f(a)}{h}$ , where $h$ is taken from $\mathbb R$

Comment: Well, yes, that is called the directional derivative of $f$ at $a$ in the direction $y$. Usually $y$ is taken as a unit vector. And yes, with $a=0$, the attached note proves exactly that: $f'(0,y)$ exists and is equal to zero for all $y$, but $f$ is not continuous at $a=(0,0)$.

Comment: I am aware of the name , yes . Well the note shows that it exists for a particular such function . It "does not prove " that all directional derivatives will exist at a point where the gradient is $\vec 0$ ...

Comment: To which of the following don't you agree? 1. All partial derivatives are zero at $(0,0)$ (in particular the gradient is zero). 2. The function is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: simply put : Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be a function such that for some $a \in \mathbb R^2$ , $\nabla f(a)$ exists and is the null vector . Then is it true that all directional derivatives of $f$ exist at $a$ ?

Comment: Well, that's a different question. Your original title does not ask it. So now you are asking whether a continuous function whose gradient exist and equals zero at some point has directional derivatives there?

Comment: For your second function , $\dfrac {\partial f}{\partial x} =(1/3) y^{1/3} / x^{2/3} $ , so how is it defined at $(0,0)$ ?

Comment: The function you wrote obviously is not defined at $(0,0)$, but you do not need it to compute the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$, which you do by the definition of the limits defining them. Your formula is valid for $x\neq 0$, and the partial derivaitve at $(0,0)$ is equal to zero. Of course, the partial derivative is not continuous at zero, or else we would not be able to construct this example!

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily even continuous at the point since the derivatives only tell you about continuity in the directions of the coordinate axes.  As a counterexample consider
$$f(x,y)= x^2+y^2, x \neq y$$
$$=1, x=y \neq 0$$
$$=0, x=y=0$$

At (0,0), $\nabla f = <0,0>,$ but the function is not continuous at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Let $f:\Reals^{2} \to \Reals$ be a function, and assume $\nabla f(0) = 0$.

1. Is $f$ necessarily continuous at $0$?

   - No: Define
     $$
     f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
       1 & \text{if $y = x^{2}$ and $x \neq 0$,} \\
       0 & \text{otherwise.}
     \end{cases}
     $$
     In this example, all *directional* derivatives of $f$ exist and are $0$ at the origin, but $f$ is discontinuous at the origin. (The file linked by uniquesolution gives a *rational* function having the same properties.)

[image: A discontinuous function possessing arbitrary directional derivatives]

2. Do all the directional derivatives of $f$ exist at $0$?

   - No: Define
     $$
     f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
       0 & \text{if $xy = 0$,} \\
       1 & \text{otherwise.}
     \end{cases}
     $$
     (As Paul notes, partial derivatives at the origin only measure behavior along the coordinate axes.)
3. What if $f$ is continuous?

   - No: Define $f(x, y) = \min\bigl(|x|, |y|\bigr)$, which vanishes along both coordinate axes (so both partials exist at the origin) and is continuous (as the minimum of two continuous functions), but fails to have directional derivatives at the origin along every non-coordinate direction.